# Activate used Verizon iPhone 6 without sim?

Tags: iphone, sim

I recently purchased a used iPhone 6, originally on the Verizon network. I'm an app developer, and as such, only need to be able to use this phone over wifi. However, when I boot up the phone I reach a "SIM Required" screen.

Is there a way to bypass this restriction or do I need to buy a cheap prepaid plan to overcome it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the phone is carrier locked, your best bet is to establish service with Verizon and get it unlocked. It's probably unlocked though so you might have luck putting any carrier's valid SIM into the phone. The SIM doesn't necessarily even need to be active - just that it once was valid and used.

Basically a Verizon sim will get you past the screen, possibly others as well initially.

Comment: @stkent Yeah, just buy an old dummy Verizon nano-SIM card off of eBay for a few dollars.

Answer (score 2):

All Verizon LTE-capable phones come unlocked due to an agreement between Verizon and the FCC. As mentioned, any nano-SIM will work, active or inactive.